# Start at option in the middle of option range [Select box]

Tags: html, html-select

I have a select box where the user can select the year s/he was born and I would like to start at 1970 when clicked but still keep "year" as the selected option by default.

Is there anyway (i.e. with JavaScript) I can start in the middle of the option range, like 1970, and have earlier years above and later years below?

Example:

```
           <select>
                <option selected>Year</option>
                <option value="1950">1950</option>
                <option value="1951">1951</option>
                <option value="1952">1952</option>
                <option value="1953">1953</option>
                <option value="1954">1954</option>
                <option value="1955">1955</option>
                <option value="1956">1956</option>
                <option value="1957">1957</option>
                <option value="1958">1958</option>
                <option value="1959">1959</option>
                <option value="1960">1960</option>
                <option value="1961">1961</option>
                <option value="1962">1962</option>
                <option value="1963">1963</option>
                <option value="1964">1964</option>
                <option value="1965">1965</option>
                <option value="1966">1966</option>
                <option value="1967">1967</option>
                <option value="1968">1968</option>
                <option value="1969">1969</option>
                <option value="1970">1970</option>
                <option value="1971">1971</option>
                <option value="1972">1972</option>
                <option value="1973">1973</option>
                <option value="1974">1974</option>
                <option value="1975">1975</option>

        </select>
```

Comment: Different platforms render `select` elements in very different ways.  Even if there is a way to do this I wouldn't expect it to be universal by any means.

Comment: Thanks for your response David - I guess I can stop looking for a solution then. ;)